# Programmatically created UIElement 'unlinks' when local variable value is set to a new UIElement

Tags: c#, wpf

Hopefully the title isn't to vague, I'm not sure how else to word it. What I'm trying to do (As a basic example) is add a rectangle to a canvas programmatically, then at some later point change the local variable to a new rectangle with different properties and have that update on the canvas.

```
// First rectangle
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle()
{
    Width = 50,
    Height = 50,
    Fill = Brushes.Red,
    Margin = new Thickness(20, 20, 0, 0)
};

// Add it to the canvas
mainCanvas.Children.Add(rect);

// Change something about the rectangle, which works
rect.Fill = Brushes.Black;

// Create new rectangle
Rectangle newRect = new Rectangle()
{
    Width = 15,
    Height = 20,
    Fill = Brushes.Blue,
    Margin = new Thickness(20, 20, 0, 0)
};

// Set the original rectangle to the new rectangle
rect = newRect;

// Canvas rectangle is no longer 'linked' to the rect variable :(
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reassigning a the `rect` variable, but that doesn't affect your Canvas. The Canvas only knows about the old rectangle `rect` used to point to. `rect` is just a reference to a rectangle. When you add it to the canvas, the canvas copies the reference. It doesn't continue to use the `rect` variable anymore. So changing `rect` to reference a new rectangle changes nothing for the canvas, as the canvas still references the original.

You likely will want to do something like the following. I'm just taking a stab here, so you might need to look up appropriate methods, but hopefully this gives you guidance.

```
mainCanvas.Children.Remove(rect); //take the old rectangle off the canvas
rect = newRect;
mainCanvas.Children.Add(rect); //replace the new rectangle on the canvas
```

Comment: That was it! It was pretty simple, the variable was stored in a different class and reassigned in that class through a method, so accessing the canvas wasn't possible. I just passed it the canvas as a parameter, and used the code you suggested. Cheers!